# Overloading + Operator in C++ for a Dynamically Allocated Type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to override the + operator for a type whose constructor involves calling new (that is, the constructor needs to dynamically allocate something else) and hence whose destructor involves calling delete.  Somewhere, I'd like to be able to use something like:

```
T c = a + b;
```

My problem is that I obviously need to create an object of type T inside the + function.  If I allocate a temporary instance of T on the stack inside the + function implementation to return by-copy, the destructor to this instance will get called as the + call exits and (or so I believe) before the assignment to c.  So that's not an option.  My other option seems to be to use `new` and dereference the pointer returned by new when returning.  It seems that the problem with this approach, however, is that the pointer will be inaccessible, and there will be no way to call `delete` on it.

So my question is...it can't be that overloading operators on types that involve dynamic allocation is that rare.  How do people generally handle such a situation?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If your type `T` has `new` in its constructor and `delete` in its destructor, for some member, then what's the issue?

Comment: I'd like to write T c = a+b;  The problem is that the + function needs to return an object of type T.  Where should I create this object?  On the stack in the + function wouldn't work - it would have delete called on it when going out of scope, which would be when it returns from the + function, right before the necessary assignment!  Should I use the new keyword and then dereference when returning?  But then I could never recover the pointer returned by new and I could never delete on it, causing a memory leak.

Comment: Hmmm...does the copy constructor get called automatically when returning a value by copy?  Something like that would be necessary to make what I'm trying to do work.  Is this what the designers of C++ implemented to solve this kind of problem (hence the mention of copy constructors in the other post?)

Comment: Yes, of course (though the copy may, under many conditions, be elided by the optimiser). If your copy constructor is wise to deep copies (as it should be anyway) then there is no issue here. Seems like you're over-thinking things. Follow the usual rule of three, as Benjamin says, and you'll be fine...

Comment: Cool, I just didn't know the copy constructor would be invoked on a return from a method.  To be clear, are we saying that every method return on a non-primitive type invokes a copy constructor behind the covers?

Comment: We are. As long as you remember that optimisations may result in the copy being elided. And bear references in mind, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make sure T obeys [The Rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and there are no worries.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Your link made me realize that my code could be prone to strange memory errors because I haven't made a copy constructor.  What about the worries that I've directly spelled out, though?  Why will following the rule of three save me from the situation I've outlined above?

Comment: @Gravity: Because `return` makes a copy of the return value (unless NRVO takes place, see @tg's answer, but then destruction is delayed).

Comment: Right, I understand now.  I didn't know returning invoked a copy constructor instead of doing a bitwise (C-style) copy.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a temporary object on stack within `operator+`, then on exit, depending on compiler and your operator implementation:

1. The object will be passed via copy constructor to another temporary object, which will be passed to `c` via copy constructor again. *OR*
2. The object will be passed to `c` via copy constructor. *OR*
3. The temporary object will be actually `c` and there will be no copy constructor calls. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

As mentioned before, if you follow The Rule of 3 and provide correct implementation of copy constructor and assignment operator there won't be any problems under any circumstances, so you don't need to worry about actual implementation (unless you're crazy about performance). That's all about OOP.

Comment: +1.  My problem was that I just didn't understand how passing-by-copy worked.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` and `std::vector` are somehow able to do that, and your class is too. I don't suggest you learn their source code, it's quite intimidating. As another poster said, the rule of 3 is your friend. I can add that you should *not* call `new` in your function. Allocate on the stack and return by value. C++ will do the necessary magic.